# Trouble with an old java applet

Tags: java, plugins, applet, physics

We're using [this website](http://webphysics.davidson.edu/physletprob/ch10_modern/default.html) to teach modern physics at our university.  I've noticed that modules 10.1.1 and 10.1.2 work on some computers but not others (on some the animations wont appear, but you still get a grid and timer).  These computers have the same hardware and set up as far as I can tell.  Also on certain computers 10.1.1 will run, but 10.1.2 will not. I am at a loss.  The trouble occurs only with these applets and not with other java modules on the website.  Have any idea what it could be and if there could be a fix?

Comment: Applets are a dead technology; almost all modern browsers have removed them.

Comment: As @ElliottFrisch points out, applets are no longer widely supported. You would have to document and restrict users to very specific and old versions of browsers. This would in turn expose your users to security vulnerabilities. You should not use applets as they were always a bad technology.

Comment: Is there any way to download this and convert to an executable jar or some other file to avoid security problems?  They have a directory here : http://webphysics.davidson.edu/Applets/jars/

Comment: You will need to create a web app using the same logic.

Comment: *"Is there any way to download this and convert to an executable jar"* Yes. But I think @PM77-1 suggested a better approach. There is basically nothing you'd need for a physics animation other than JS and the `canvas` element of HTML 5. Further, it will be better than the applet ever was, for a variety of reasons.